# Unable to create dynamic terraform outputs for use in terraform_remote_state

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have the following code block for creating various IAM groups

```
resource "aws_iam_group" "environment-access" {
  count = "${length(var.environments)}"
  name = "access-${element(var.environments, count.index)}"
}

variable "environments" {
  default = ["production", "non-production"]
  type = "list"
}
```

I want to write the outputs of the IAM groups created in order to grab the ARN of each group to use as data via terraform_remote_state where it would look something like the following

```
Outputs:

access-production = arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:group/basepath/access-production
access-non-production = arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:group/basepath/access-non-production
```

I am having trouble creating the dynamic outputs as I am unsure how to dynamically create the output stanzas based on the the resource originally created as using the below code yields an error referencing unknown resource 'aws_iam_group.access-production' referenced.

```
output "access-production" {
  value = "${aws_iam_group.access-production.arn}"
}

output "access-non-production" {
  value = "${aws_iam_group.access-non-production.arn}"
}
```

Comment: What version of Terraform are you using?

Comment: I am using v0.11.13

Answer (score 1):

An initial problem with this requirement is that it calls for having a single dynamic list of environments but multiple separate output values. In order to make this work, you'll need to either make the environment inputs separate values or produce a single output value describing the environments.

```
# Variant with a fixed set of environments (v0.11 syntax)

variable "production_environment_name" {
  type    = "string"
  default = "production"
}

variable "non_production_environment_name" {
  type    = "string"
  default = "non-production"
}

resource "aws_iam_group" "production_access" {
  name = "access-${var.production_environment_name}"
}

resource "aws_iam_group" "non_production_access" {
  name = "access-${var.non_production_environment_name}"
}

output "access_production" {
  value = "aws_iam_group.production_access.arn"
}

output "access_non_production" {
  value = "aws_iam_group.non_production_access.arn"
}
```

```
# Variant with dynamic set of environments (v0.11 syntax)

variable "environments" {
  type    = "list"
  default = ["production", "non_production"]
}

resource "aws_iam_group" "access" {
  count = "${length(var.environments)}"

  name = "access-${var.environments[count.index]}"
}

output "access" {
  value = "${aws_iam_group.access.*.arn}"
}
```

The key here is that the input variable and the output value must have the same form, so that we can make all of the necessary references between the objects. In the second example, the environment names are provided as a list, and the group ARNs are also provided as a list such that the indices correspond between the two.

You can also use a variant of the `output "access"` expression to combine the two with [`zipmap`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/zipmap.html) and get a map keyed by the environment names, which will probably be more convenient for the caller to use:

```
output "access" {
  value = "${zipmap(var.environments, aws_iam_group.access.*.arn)}"
}
```

---

The new features in Terraform 0.12 allow tidying this up a bit. Here's an idiomatic Terraform 0.12 equivalent of the version that produces a map as a result:

```
# Variant with dynamic set of environments (v0.12 syntax)

variable "environments" {
  type    = set(string)
  default = ["production", "non_production"]
}

resource "aws_iam_group" "access" {
  for_each = var.environments

  name = "access-${each.key}"
}

output "access" {
  value = { for env, group in aws_iam_group.access : env => group.arn }
}
```

As well as having some slightly different syntax patterns, this 0.12 example has an additional practical advantage: Terraform will track those IAM groups with addresses like `aws_iam_group.access["production"]` and `aws_iam_group.access["non_production"]`, so the positions of the environment names in the `var.environments` list are not important and it's possible to add and remove environments without potentially disturbing the groups from other environments due to the list element renumbering.

It achieves that by using [resource `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings), which makes `aws_iam_group.access` appear as a map of objects where the environment names are keys, whereas `count` makes it a list of objects.

Comment: so with v0.11, managing 100+ environments cannot be done dynamically it sounds like if the outputs are required in order to be used as data in terraform_remote_state for other resources.

Comment: You can have as many environments as you need as long as you use the approach of having a single output whose value is a list or a map. Specifying 100 environments in would give you a list or map with 100 elements out. Terraform 0.12 just lets you express the same thing a bit more concisely. The key thing here is that the set of output _declarations_ is static, not dynamic... a single output can be a collection with as many elements as you need, though.